# SDR Bandwidth and sample rate

Tags: adc, dac, bandwidth, sampling, sdr

I saw that SDR has two parameter: bandwidth and sampling rate. I would like to know the difference between them because i saw a 56MHz bandwidth SDR but by looking at the chip used inside the sampling rate of the ADCs was 50MHz.

If i have a sampling rate of 50MHz and i want to scan a 50MHz bandwidth mean that i will update the entire band every second? And if i take 25MHz band i will update it every 0.5 seconds?

Thank you all, I hope the question is clear and not too much stupid.

Comment: link to the data sheet, the parameters you've quoted are inconsistent, or at least, consistent with dodgy specificationeering. Update time is independent of scanned bandwidth

Comment: "If i have a sampling rate of 50MHz and i want to scan a 50MHz bandwidth mean that i will update the entire band every second?" That's not what an SDR does. An SDR is not a spectrum analyzer. it doesn't scan. It samples.